# Por qué no se actualiza mi setContador

Tags: javascript, reactjs

soy muy nuevo en React, y estoy intentando cambiar el valor de 'contador'.

```
const [contador, setContador] = useState(0);
    let cont = 0;
    
    const DeterminarCont = () => {
        
      historial.forEach(h => {
        if (h.fecha.slice(0,2) === '27') {
          cont += 1;
          setContador(cont); //incluso probé con: setContador(3) por poner cualquier valor  
          console.log('Si!'); 
          console.log('contador: ', contador);
        }
      }

     useEffect(() => {
        DeterminarCont();
      }, []);
```

Por **consola** los valores son actualizados **correctamente** pero en vista no, y no entiendo por qué o como solucionarlo.

```
return ( 
      <>
        <h2>{contador}</h2> //Se mantienen en 0 en la vista, pero por consola me actualiza los n°s
        <h3>  {cont}  </h3>
      </>
    )
```

Hay alguna forma de que al entrar al componente se actualice 'contador' en la vista?, ya que solo lo hace por consola. Gracias de antemano

Comment: que es lo que almacena la variable `historial` y por qué la recorres con un `forEach`. Cabe destacar que tienes puesto un useEffect que solo se ejecuta en la primera carga del componente por lo que solo sumará una única vez al contador sin ver mucho más el código que tienes para saber exactamente qué es lo que quieres hacer

Comment: Hola, historial contiene un arreglo de fechas, por lo que cada fecha que coincida con el día 27 sumará uno a 'Contador'. Por consola 'Contador' se actualiza correctamente, pero en la vista solo se queda en 0. Lo hice con forEach y no .map porque este me tira el error "Array.prototype.map() expects a return value from arrow function". Gracias por tu tiempo amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Viendo que tienes una variable auxiliar para hacer las veces de contador, no sería necesario actualizar el estado cada vez que cuenta un nuevo item que cumple la condición, sino que puedes sumar al contador y una vez tienes el número final de items cambias el estado del contador. Esto para evitar múltiples recargas de estado.

En adición a esto he visto que el `forEach` no estaba bien cerrado ya que estaba cerrada la funcion interna pero no el paréntesis del final del `forEach`.

```js
const DeterminarCont = () => {
  let cont = 0;
  historial.forEach(h => {
    if (h.fecha.slice(0,2) === '27') {
      cont++; 
    }
  });
  setContador(cont);
}

useEffect(() => {
  DeterminarCont();
}, []);
```

Este comportamiento tambien podría conseguirse con un `reduce` de tal forma que:

```js
const DeterminarCont = () => {
  const finalCount = historial.reduce((acc, current) => current.fecha.slice(0,2) === '27' ? acc + 1 : acc, 0);
  setContador(finalCount);
}

useEffect(() => {
  DeterminarCont();
}, []);
```